# How can I avoid using a variable in a Keras Lambda layer?

Tags: keras, lambda

In my model training program, I have this fragment...

```
if args.thr > 0.0:
    s = layers.Lambda(lambda a: a / args.thr)(s)
    s = layers.Lambda(lambda a: a / (1.0+a*a))(s)
    u = layers.Subtract()([x, s])
```

The args.thr value is set by argparse. I have a separate program that loads the model, and uses it on a set of images. As this is written, if args.thr is greater than zero, the Lambda layer is included, and it will expect a value for args.thr.

I could edit the code and write the value into the Lambda line instead of passing it as an argument. Is there some way of effectively doing the same thing from an argument? This works...

```
    s = eval('layers.Lambda(lambda a: a / {0:f})(s)'.format(args.thr))
```

It isn't very pretty: I turn the float into a string, and the string back into a float, ugh. Is there a nicer way of doing this?

PS:

If there isn't support, perhaps I shouldn't be doing it. In this case, the layer has no trainable parameters, so it is not an active part of the model. I have since managed to re-arrange things so this is handled outside of the model. Nevertheless, it worked even though it wasn't perfect.

Comment: A possibility without lambda would be to define a function instead of using a lambda expression with the parameters a and thr. Afterwards, you should be able to pass `functools.partial(your_function, thr=args.thr)` to `keras.layers.Lambda`.

Comment: Thanks. This would do it. The answer was not in keras or numpy. I stall probably stick with what I had as the value is a parameter I typed in, so turning it into a string and back does no real harm.

This is a way of wrapping a function. I was expecting something that would wrap a variable as a constant, so I can see why I wasn't finding it. Thanks.